# "Unable to announce backup" warning when an ActiveMQ Artemis master/slave pair is deployed in Openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to deploy a cluster of ActiveMQ Artemis in master/slave mode in Openshift, but i get an this WARN continually:

```
2019-01-09 07:50:40,192 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222137: Unable to announce backup, retrying: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119012: Timed out waiting to receive initial broadcast from cluster]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:759) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:635) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:617) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.BackupManager$BackupConnector$1.run(BackupManager.java:246) [artemis-server-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
```

When I use this configuration in the same machine it works without problems. But when I Dockerize it and deploy one broker in each container it fails.

Here is the configuration for broker 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <name>0.0.0.0</name>
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
    <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
    <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
    <journal-buffer-timeout>36000</journal-buffer-timeout>
    <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
    <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
    <ha-policy>
     <shared-store>
      <master>
       <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
      </master>
     </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>

    <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</connector>
    </connectors>

    <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</acceptor>
    </acceptors>

    <broadcast-groups>
       <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
          <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
          <group-port>9876</group-port>
          <broadcast-period>1000</broadcast-period>
          <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
       </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

    <discovery-groups>
       <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
          <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
          <group-port>9876</group-port>
          <refresh-timeout>60000</refresh-timeout>
       </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>

    <cluster-connections>
       <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
          <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
          <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
       </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>

    <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
      </security-setting>
    </security-settings>
    <address-settings>
      <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
      <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
      </address-setting>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
      </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <addresses>
      <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="DLQ"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
      <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
    </addresses>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

Here is the configuration for broker 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <name>0.0.0.0</name>
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
    <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
    <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
    <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
    <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
    <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
    <ha-policy>
     <shared-store>
      <slave>
       <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
      </slave>
     </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>

    <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617</connector>
    </connectors>

    <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617</acceptor>
    </acceptors>

    <broadcast-groups>
       <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
          <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
          <group-port>9876</group-port>
          <broadcast-period>1000</broadcast-period>
          <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
       </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

    <discovery-groups>
       <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
          <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
          <group-port>9876</group-port>
          <refresh-timeout>60000</refresh-timeout>
       </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>

    <cluster-connections>
       <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
          <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
          <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
       </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>

    <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
        <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
      </security-setting>
    </security-settings>
    <address-settings>
      <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
      <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
      </address-setting>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
      </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <addresses>
      <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="DLQ"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
      <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
    </addresses>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

After enabling `DEBUG` logging this shows up:

```
2019-01-10 15:40:37,753 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.BackupManager] DiscoveryBackupConnector [group=DiscoveryGroupConfiguration{name='dg-group1', refreshTimeout=60000, discoveryInitialWaitTimeout=10000}]:: announcing TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=10-130-0-119 to ServerLocatorImpl (identity=backupLocatorFor='ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=0cef6ba4-14ee-11e9-83b3-0a580a820077') [initialConnectors=[], discoveryGroupConfiguration=DiscoveryGroupConfiguration{name='dg-group1', refreshTimeout=60000, discoveryInitialWaitTimeout=10000}]
```

Comment: Can you confirm that multicast communication is working properly between the two Docker instances?

Comment: Excuse me, but how i can check this?

Comment: Ports for this communications are Opened (9876 UDP & TCP)

Comment: How do you run your containers?

Comment: @grapes oc new-app <image-name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here...

First, your connector configurations are incorrect.  On broker 1 you're using this:

```
<connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616</connector>
```

And on broker 2 you're using this:

```
<connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617</connector>
```

This connector information is sent by each member of the cluster to inform other cluster members how they can connect back to the node which sent the information. For example, in your case broker 1 is telling broker 2 that it can connect back to broker 1 using `tcp://0.0.0.0:61616`. This is, of course, not true since the meta-address `0.0.0.0` doesn't actually point to broker 1. When broker 2 tries to use this URL it will fail as you're seeing.

The reason this works when running both brokers on the same host is because `0.0.0.0` will resolve the same as `localhost`.

You need to use a valid IP address or hostname in your connector configurations so that the cluster can form properly.

Second, the `DEBUG` logging you provided indicates that multicast traffic isn't working between the two Docker instances. I recommend you try using *static* clustering to remove multicast problems from the environment. On broker 1 you can use something like:

```
<connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://broker1:61616</connector>
     <connector name="broker2-connector">tcp://broker2:61617</connector>
</connectors>

...

<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
      <static-connectors>
         <connector-ref>broker2-connector</connector-ref>
      </static-connectors>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

On broker 2 you can use something like:

```
<connectors>
     <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://broker2:61617</connector>
     <connector name="broker1-connector">tcp://broker1:61616</connector>
</connectors>

...

<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
      <static-connectors>
         <connector-ref>broker1-connector</connector-ref>
      </static-connectors>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

Of course you'll need to use the IP address or hostnames for the actual nodes in the connectors.

Comment: Hi Justin, First.. thanks for your answer. I´ve changed the configuration of my brokers with the IP of the container as follows:      [link](https://pastebin.com/ND8SXXwW). But nothing change. I am receiving the same WARN.

Comment: I updated your question with the relevant logging and my answer with details on how to address the issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand your new configuration, but there are new troubles. I let you [here](https://pastebin.com/3nnHeUFh) logs of master-broker and [here](https://pastebin.com/X8p1ZDv8) logs of slave-broker. I thougth is a problem of connection between containers, but containers are visibles between them. Kind regards and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This looks like basic connectivity problems between the two Docker instances. I'm not a Docker expert so I'm not sure what (if anything) needs to be done to enable network communication between Docker instances, but I would recommend you try a simple connectivity test between the two instances (something like `ping`), and if that doesn't work then do some research on Docker network connectivity.

Comment: OK, thank you so much for your responses, I will try to reproduce this in two instances of centos 7. I will tell you what happened. PD: basic connectivity between both containers are OK. ping is OK and ports are openned.

Comment: Hi @Justin once again, I have tried to reproduce this situation and doesn´t work. I let you the configuration of [broker-slave](https://pastebin.com/HcEhMy7S) and [broker-master](https://pastebin.com/a2cq3E5x) and the logs of them: [logsbroker-slave](https://pastebin.com/17GYKwHB) [logsbroker-master](https://pastebin.com/K87P9CDm). In addiction, this time i will show you my Java class and application properties: [sender](https://pastebin.com/nBMwN5z8)  [consumer](https://pastebin.com/XbcGK2yG) . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Finally works, but the problem were not the connection. Artemis does not work with NFS

Comment: Artemis does work with NFSv4. Lots of users do that.

Comment: Correct, I used NFSv2 and didn´t work, but if you use NFSv4 works without problems. Tank you so much for your time @Justin